# ASP.NET Web API cannot return XML if the returned object has an IList<T> property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm using ASP.NET Web API's ApiController to expose business logic as a Web service.  I'm testing both XML and JSON, since we have demand for both, and I've been using Fiddler to test.  I've narrowed it down to this: having an `IList<T>` property forces JSON for some reason, but changing the property to `List<T>` allows either JSON or XML.  Unfortunately, I need these to use `IList<T>`, so how can I make XML out of objects with `IList<T>` properties?

If I use the following HTML headers to GET `http://localhost:4946/Api/MyBizLog/GetDomainObject?id=foo`:

```
Authorization: basic ***************
Accept: application/xml
Host: localhost:4946
```

I get back JSON if an exception is thrown.  If I change `Content-Type` to `Content-Type: application/xml`, I get XML if an exception is thrown.  If an exception is *not* thrown, however, I always get JSON.

The method I'm calling has a signature like `public virtual MyDomainObject GetDomainObject(String id)`.

How do I get it to return the content type I ask for on success as well as failure?

I have the following WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "AlternativeApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { }
        );

        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
    }
}
```

***More Information***

I installed WebAPI tracing per @Darren Miller's suggestion, and I get the following:

I put a breakpoint on the first line of the action.  I then sent the GET from Fiddler.  The output showed the following when execution stopped at the breakpoint:

```
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=GET, Url=http://localhost:4946/Api/MyBizLog/GetDomainObject?id=foo, Message='http://localhost:4946/Api/MyBizLog/GetDomainObject?id=foo'
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='MyBizLog', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='WebApp.Api.MyBizLogController', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='WebApp.Api.MyBizLogController', Operation=HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected action 'GetDomainObject(String id)'', Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Parameter 'id' bound to the value 'foo'', Operation=ModelBinderParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Model state is valid. Values: id=foo', Operation=HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=TransactionalApiFilterAttribute.ActionExecuting
```

I then let execution continue, and I got the following:

```
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Action returned 'DomainObjects.MyDomainObject'', Operation=ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Will use same 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected formatter='JsonMediaTypeFormatter', content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=ApiControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsync, Status=200 (OK)
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=TransactionalApiFilterAttribute.ActionExecuted, Status=200 (OK)
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=MyBizLogController.ExecuteAsync, Status=200 (OK)
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=200 (OK), Method=GET, Url=http://localhost:4946/Api/MyBizLog/GetDomainObject?id=foo, Message='Content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8', content-length=unknown'
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Operation=MyBizLogController.Dispose
```

I do have an `ActionFilterAttribute` that reads the basic authentication and tells the business logic layer who the current user is, but skipping that doesn't change the results.

***Yet More Information***

So I've narrowed it down to IList and List.  If I `#define WORKS`, I get XML.  If I `#define DOESNT_WORK`, I get JSON.  This is actually code that actually runs.

```
        public class Bar
        {
        }

        public class Foo
        {
#if WORKS
            public virtual List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
#elif DOESNT_WORK
            public virtual IList<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
#endif
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [HttpGet]
        public Foo Test()
        {
            return new Foo();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are using the wrong header.  `Content-Type` is used to describe the payload you are transferring.  In the case of a GET there is no payload, therefore there is no need for Content-Type or Content-Length.  You should be setting the `Accept` header to indicate your preference of the media type that will be returned.

Comment: Darrel --  You are right that Accept should be used.  Using `Accept: application/xml`, unfortunately, produces the same results.  I've modified the question to reflect your correction, though I suppose the question still stands.

Comment: @Don01001100 You most likely have some issue in your domain object that prevents the XML serializer from being able to render it.  Install/enable the WebAPI tracing, that should tell you why it is not working.

Comment: I didn't see anything that was an obvious problem to me.  Can you take a look?  I added the output to my question.

Comment: @Don01001100 Do you have cycles in your MyDomainObject?  I.e. It points to an object that points back to it?  the XmlSerializer will choke on that I believe.

Comment: I don't.  I wrote a utility called OneWayCopier that copies my domain objects with no cycles expressly for that purpose.  See my newest additions above.

Comment: Any ideas, @Darrel Miller?  Or anyone else?

Comment: @Don01001100 From what I understand, XmlSerializer can't handle interfaces.  Either change your property to List<>, implement IXmlSerializable on your class, or use DataContractSerializer.  Or even better, don't try and return domain objects across the wire.

Answer (score 3):

@Darrel Miller has the answer:

> From what I understand, XmlSerializer can't handle interfaces. Either
>   change your property to List<>, implement IXmlSerializable on your
>   class, or use DataContractSerializer. Or even better, don't try and
>   return domain objects across the wire.

Answer (score 1):

Just like @Patrick mentioned, @Darrel's answer is correct.  I am not suggesting a different answer here, this is only a solution as whole, just in case anyone else stumbles here:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("myRoute")]
[ResponseType(typeof(MyCustomModel))]
/* Note: If your response type is of type IEnumerable, i.e. IEnumerable<MyCustomModel>, then Example in Swagger will look like this: 

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Inline Model>
    <AttributeIdProperty>string</AttributeIdProperty>
    <PropertyForElement>string</PropertyForElement>
</Inline Model>

The real output will be correct representation, however:

<ArrayOfMyCustomModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<MyCustomModel AttributeIdProperty="Value for this attribute property">
    <PropertyForElement>Value for this element property</PropertyForElement>
</MyCustomModel>
</ArrayOfContentMetadata>
*/
public virtual IHttpActionResult MyMethod([FromBody]MyCustomModel myCustomModel)
{
    if (myCustomModel== null) throw new Exception("Invalid input", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    return Ok(_myBusiness.MyMethod(myCustomModel);
}
```

Model:

```
public class MyCustomModel : IXmlSerializable
{
    [JsonProperty("attributeIdProperty ")]
    [XmlAttribute("AttributeIdProperty")]
    public string AttributeIdProperty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("propertyForElement ")]
    [XmlElement("PropertyForElement ")]
    public string PropertyForElement { get; set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.MoveToContent() == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == "MyCustomModel")
        {
            AttributeIdProperty = reader["AttributeIdProperty"];
            PropertyForElement = reader["PropertyForElement"];
            reader.Read();
        }
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteAttributeString("AttributeIdProperty", AttributeIdProperty);
        writer.WriteElementString("PropertyForElement", PropertyForElement);
    }
}
```

Web API Config:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Filters.Add(new GlobalExceptionFilter());
        //below line is what's most important for this xml serialization
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
    }
}
```

Swagger Config:

```
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {

        var swaggerHeader = new SwaggerHeader();

        ///...

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
            {
                swaggerHeader.Apply(c);
            });
```

Swagger Header:

```
public class SwaggerHeader : IOperationFilter
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void Apply(SwaggerDocsConfig c)
    {
        c.ApiKey(Key).Name(Name).Description(Description).In("header");
        c.OperationFilter(() => this);
    }

    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        if (!operation.produces.Contains("application/xml")) operation.produces.Add("application/xml");
        if (!operation.produces.Contains("text/xml")) operation.produces.Add("text/xml");
    }
}
```