# IList<> returned type instead of List<>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, generics

I found this method in one of examples for dependency [Injecting a Controller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvcdependencyinjection_topic2). What is the reason of using an interface type `IList<>` instead of `List<>`?

```
public IList<string> GetGenreNames()
{
    var genres = from genre in storeDB.Genres
                 select genre.Name;
    return genres.ToList();
}
```

Comment: This allows you to change the method implementation without affecting its users. Check out [LSP principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: If you need to support encoding the return of this method using the application/xml mime type, be sure to test your setup.  The XmlSerializer typically used to handle this serialization may not support serializing List<string>.

Answer (score 4):

The *actual* reason, you're going to go ask the original programmer of that method that.

We can come up with a plausible reason however.

- Input parameters should be as open and general as possible. Don't take an array if you can use any collection type that can be enumerated over. (ie. prefer `IEnumerable<int>` over `List<int>` if all you're going to do is do a `foreach`)
- Output parameters and return types should be as specific as possible, but try to return the most usable and flexible data type possible without sacrificing performance or security. Don't return a collection that can only be enumerated over (like `IEnumerable<int>`) if you can return an array or a list you created specifically for the results (like `int[]` or `List<int>`).

These guidelines are listed many places on the internet (in different words though) and are there to help people write good APIs.

The reason why `IList<T>` is better than `List<T>` is that you're returning a collection that can be:

- Enumerated over (streaming access)
- Accessed by index (random access)
- Modified (Add, Delete, etc.)

If you were to return `List<T>` you wouldn't actually add any value, except to return a concrete type instead of just *any* type that happens to implement that interface. As such, it is better to return the interface and not the concrete type. You don't lose any useful features on the outside and you still retain the possibility of replacing the actual object returned with something different in the future.

Comment: If you use web api and are supporting application/xml and you return IList<T> you may run into issues.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114175/asp-net-web-api-cannot-return-xml-if-the-returned-object-has-an-ilistt-propert

Comment: The IList does not guarantee that it is modifiable. Add/Remove are not guaranteed to be implemented and the IsFixedSize & IsReadOnly properties need to be checked before calling Add/Remove [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.add). The added value of returning List is the guarantee that it is never read only, in addition to the extra convenience methods like AddRange. In my experience the client nearly always calls ToList on the received IList which results in a unnecessary copy.

Comment: I agree than Interfaces are neater for APIs, but microsoft badly messed up the collection interfaces resulting in this crap

Answer (score 2):

targeting interface is always better than targeting concrete type.

So if returning IList,  that means anything implementing IList could be returned, give better separation.

check this out for more info

[Why is it considered bad to expose List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387937/why-is-it-considered-bad-to-expose-listt)

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat basic rule in OOP. It's good to have an interface so your clients (the caller of GetGenreNames ) knows only how to call (function signature, only thing to remember, rather than implementation details etc) to get serviced.

Programming to interface supports all goodies of OOP. its more generalized, maintains separation of concerns, more reusable.